# Why isn't this a total order relation?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let's say,

*if a < (b-ε): a < b*

*elif a > (b+ε): a > b*

*else: a==b*

The professor said this does not satisfy a total order because of transitivity.
what is related between this problem and transitivity?

Comment: Here you define at the same time a strict ordering ">" (or "<") and an equivalence relation "==". If we require "==" to be indeed an equivalence relation, the all reals are "==" to each other. If we are not interested in equivalence, then it would be better to either drop this part (if we are interested in a strict ordering) or include into the relation "$\leq$" (if we are interested in a non-strict ordering).

Comment: What is $\epsilon$?  Is it fixed?  And you are defining $<$ in terms of itself.  This doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Can you edit for clarity?  Are these real numbers?  Something else?  Are you using $<$ to denote more than one thing?  As it stands, it is hard to make much sense out of your question.